How to adjust mongoose query for Atlas Search?
This is my Index Definition in Monodb Atlas Search.
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "title": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}

This is my query.
const searchPipeline = ({query}) => {

  return [
    {
      $search: {
        index: "default", 
        text: {
          query,
          path: ["title"], 
          fuzzy: {
            maxEdits: 2, 
            prefixLength: 1, 
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ];
};

Problem is that when query is "audi a2" it matches everything that has "audi" in title. I want it to behave following way:

query="audi" -> match everything with "audi" in title
query="audi a2" -> match everything with "audi a2" in title but not "audi a1", "audi a3" etc...

I'm not into BE much but I am learning new stuff at the moment. ChatGPT wasn't helpful at all.
